# "getline" prompt gets skipped, not working as intended

Tags: c++, getline

Here are my codes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age1;
    int age2;
    string name1;
    string name2;

cout << "Please enter the name for one people: " << "\n";
getline (cin, name1);
cout << "Please enter the age for this people: " << "\n";
cin >> age1;

cout << "Please enter the name for another people: " << "\n";
getline (cin, name2);
cout << "Please enter the age for this people too: " << "\n";
cin >> age2;

if ( (age1 <= 100 || age2 <= 100) && (age1 < age2) )
{
    cout << name1 << " is younger!" << "\n";
}
else if ( (age1 <= 100 || age2 <= 100) && (age1 > age2) )
{
    cout << name2 << " is younder!" << "\n";
}
else if ( (age1 <= 100 || age2 <= 100) && (age1 = age2) )
{
    cout << name1 << " and " << name2 << " are of the same age!" << "\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "You've got some really old people that are well older than 100!";
}
}
```

The first getline and cin works fine. I am able to be prompted to input.
However, the second getline and cin are prompted at once, thus I can only input for cin. (The second getline is skipped!)

If I use four cins, the program will work properly.

Comment: Reminder: the streams controlled by `cin` and `cout` aren't actually related at all; the appearance of such is an artifact of how your console works and typical I/O patterns. It is very easy to confuse yourself by assuming that the individual uses of `cin` and `cout` bear a relationship they don't have. (the objects themselves do have a relationship in being `tied`, although that isn't really relevant here. It means that if `cin` runs out of data, it will flush `cout` before it requests more data from the operating system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cin >> age1;` does not read the newline character following the number. The newline remains in the input buffer, then prematurely stops the second `getline`.

So, your program [already works](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0f434d374743cd3) as long as you enter the first age and the second name on the same line.

One solution would be to skip whitespace after the numbers:

```
cin >> age1 >> ws;
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/548fd2d6c4560cf9).

Answer (score 1):

**first:** cin>>age; It takes the number and stores into age but at the same
time it leaves the newline character in the buffer itself. so when there is prompt for next name cin finds that left over newline character in the buffer and takes it as the input. that it why it escapes the name2 prompt.

```
    cout << "Please enter the name for one people: " << "\n";       
    cin>>name1;
    cout << "Please enter the age for this people: " << "\n";
    cin >> age1;<<--**this left the new line character in input buffer**
    cin.get();<<-- **get that newline charachter out of there first**
    cout << "Please enter the name for another people: " << "\n";
    getline (cin, name2);
    cout << "Please enter the age for this people too: " << "\n";
    cin >> age2;
```

**now** i give name1-> shishir age1->28
name2->ccr age-> 22 it prints ccr is **younder!**<-- *the spelling is wrong too :D*

**for more info** on getline and get() read c++ primer plus **listing 4.3, 4.4, 4.5**

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You need a `;` after `getline (cin, name);`

hope this helps

Comment: I forgot the ";" when I rewrote that two lines. In the original program there are ";"s. And I just tried again, even with ";", it still skips the second getline. I edited the code to add ";".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using cin.ignore(100,'\n'). It ignores the amount of characters you specify when you call it(100 in the example above), up to the char you specify as a breakpoint. For example:

```
cout << "Please enter the name for one people: " << "\n";
getline (cin, name1);
cout << "Please enter the age for this people: " << "\n";
cin >> age1;
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
cout << "Please enter the name for another people: " << "\n";
getline (cin, name2);
cout << "Please enter the age for this people too: " << "\n";
cin >> age2;
cin.ignore(100, '\n');
```